# Cohen's Kappa in R Studio for 3 variables out of 2 tables (2 raters)

Tags: r, statistics, cohen-kappa

I have to define the Cohen's Kappa of 2 raters (inter-rater reliability; IRR). I have 2 excel tables for each rater and need to take 3 columns out of those tables and compare the values.

This is what I tried and it didn't function at all.

```
install.packages('DescTools')
library(DescTools)

ratertab <- xtabs(IRR_1$1 + IRR_2$1)

CohenKappa(ratertab)
```

Should I create one common table with those 3 variables and which commands should I better use?

Thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: What was your error message ?

Comment: `IRR_1$1` is definitely wrong, should it be `IRR_1[[1]]`? And the same for `IRR_2$1`.